# My sqlite3 database/queries are very slow. Switch or fix queries?

Tags: sqlite

I have a large sqlite db. Its 185mb.

This query is taking about 5seconds and it returns 2 rows. I added an index to user.name than Content.user_id. It stills take many seconds. Can sqlite handle large files like this? Is there a simple fix for a private app like telling sqlite to put everything in ram on app startup? (Its C#.NET for dev use only).

```
select Content.*,name from user 
                join Content on Content.user_id=user.id 
                where user.name like 'some_name' order by some_col ASC;
```

Comment: "I added an index to user.name than Content.user_id" ; do you mean you added two indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- Replace `LIKE 'some_name'` with `= 'some_name'`. [LIKE queries with underscore or percent sign will not perform as well as equality checks](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html). Depending on the position of the first percentage sign or underscore they might be unable to use your index on `user.name`.
- Launch `ANALYZE`.

**Followup to your answer**:

I think you have case-insensitive LIKE pragma enabled. This means that:

You should recreate your database and use `name COLLATE NOCASE` in the definition of the `name` column of table users. Thus, all comparison tests on user names will be case insensitive, and so will your index be. This way, a case-insensitive LIKE can use the index also.

Comment: `=` doesnt seem to work and the name is correct including capitalization. I cant figure out how to use analyze. I looked at [the page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) and wrote `ANALYZE user;` and saw nothing. -edit- also the name i am testing with is theTestUser

Comment: @acidzombie24, see followup in my answer.

Comment: If the name is correct including capitalization, what returns `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='...'`?

Comment: Apparently my database is 'malformed'. I believe i can regenerate this in a minute or two.

Comment: ok not only does `=` work correctly but now its very fast. The problem was the database was corrupt/malformed and now its fine. I THINK in my app using like was still slow and = was fast while the sqlite command line app both was fast. I'm not sure why but anyways this is completely fixed. Accepeted

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check your [indexes](http://www.indigorose.com/forums/threads/24472-SQLite-indexes-and-how-to-use-them)